# How to add SMTP in .NetCore without credentials when the mail server is within the local network

Tags: c#, smtp, .net-core-2.1

How to setup my SMTP client in .NET Core 2.1 without credentials. My mail server is within the network.

```
private async Task<bool> SendEmailToCustomer(string customerEmail, string Message)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SmtpConfig.server);

        if (SmtpConfig.userName != "" && SmtpConfig.password != "")
        {
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpConfig.userName, SmtpConfig.password);
        }

        //client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(SmtpConfig.fromForCustomer);
        mailMessage.To.Add(customerEmail);
        mailMessage.Body = Message;
        mailMessage.Subject = SmtpConfig.subjectForCustomer;
        await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get with the current code?

Comment: You do know that pattern of just returning false when you face an exception is a bad one, right? You're losing valuable information there. At least log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change its simple no need to set credentials to the `smtpclient`